# How to combine 2 flash games in one with menu?

Tags: actionscript-3, button, flash-cs6

I have created two games in Flash and AS3 in different files and want to combine them with a menu created on a third file. Do I import them or copy paste them? Should the ActionScript be on the game line or should they all be in the same actions layer?

How do I set up the menu? Everything I do seems to mess it up somehow.

I have an animated start menu that has a Start and an About the Game button.
When you click the Start button (start123_btn) it takes you to a menu where you can choose from two games (which I then want to hook up with the two games I have created and in those games I want a way to return to the main menu).

The About the Game button takes you to another button that gives some details about the games which I want that when they click it it takes them back to the main menu (frame 60).

Any advice?

Comment: So far all I have is 

'import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();

start123_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, menu);
function menu(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 gotoAndStop(70)
}
about_btn123.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, about);
function about(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 gotoAndStop(60);
}'

Comment: I am kind of new at this so I'm still a bit confused as to how things are put together.

Answer (score 3):

### tl;dr

Create a third SWF that load each game using a `Loader`.
Add `startGame()` and `stopGame()` methods to each game to control them.

### details

Create a wrapper that defines the menu and load each game. When the game is loaded, call `startGame()` to initialize the SWF. `stopGame()` could be called before closing the game.

```
public class Game1 extends MovieClip
{
    public function startGame():void
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function stopGame():void
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Do the same with the second game.

Comment: Thank you, but if you could be more spesific, what do I put inside the brackets?

Comment: When using a `Loader`, since its content is loaded, the constructor of the root object will be called. If you have put some game logic into it, you should move it into `startGame()`.